# group by with where not working

Tags: sql, database, plsql, db2

```
SELECT A.ID, A.COLUMN_B, A.COLUMN_C FROM A
WHERE A.COLUMN_A IN
 (
  SELECT A.COLUMN_A
  FROM B
  INNER JOIN A ON B."COLUMN_A" = A."COLUMN_A"
  WHERE B."COLUMN_B" = 'something'

  UNION

  SELECT A."COLUMN_A"
  FROM A  
  WHERE A."COLUMN_D" IN (X,Y,Z) OR A."COLUMN_D" = 'something'
  )
```

Now I want add a `group by (A.ID)` , and `order by (A.COLUMN_B) DESC`, and then `select first`  to it. But DB won't allow. Any suggestions ? I can use LINQ to solve it once inner Union part is returned. But do now want to go that way.

Comment: your sql is not valid. there is no FROM. It would be better if you tell what you want to achieve

Comment: PLEASE DON'T SHOUT, NOT EVEN IN YOUR TITLE

Comment: Yes, from which table are you trying to select `a.id, a.column_b,a.column_c`?

Comment: @John Saunders lol...yeah, I never really understood the need for people to type so much of their SQL in all caps, especially when keywords ('select','from','where',etc) are case-insensitive.

Comment: Sorry about that. Forgot to add From clause.

Comment: Does the keywords being written in caps has anything to do with issue ?

Comment: SQL is supposed to be case-insensitive.  The casing often seen in the SQL examples/answers posted on SO seems to be a home-grown standard.  I only follow it here, not in any of the production work I do.

Answer (score 2):

There's a couple of things here.
First off - in DB2, when using `GROUP BY`, you can only select those columns listed in the grouping statement - everything else **must** be part of an aggregation function.  So, grouping by `a.Id` and ordering by `a.Column_B` won't work - you'll need to order by `SUM(a.Column_B)` or something applicable.
Second... your query could use a bit of work in the general sense - specifically, you're self-joining twice, which you don't need to do at all.  Try this instead:

```
SELECT a.Id, SUM(a.Column_B) as total, SUM(a.Column_C)
FROM a
WHERE a.Column_D in (X, Y, Z, 'Something')
OR EXISTS (SELECT '1'
           FROM b
           WHERE b.Column_A = a.Column_A
           AND b.Column_B = 'Something')
GROUP BY a.Id
ORDER BY total DESC
FETCH FIRST 1 ROW ONLY
```

Swap out the `SUM` function for whatever is appropriate.

Answer (score 0):

You can't use a column in the ORDER BY or SELECT that you haven't included in the GROUP BY, unless it's being aggregated (in a function like MAX() or COUNT() or SUM().

So, you could GROUP BY A.ID,A.COLUMN_B, and then ORDER BY COLUMN_B. Using a TOP 1 should work, too.

I just noticed that you're on DB2.  I know that it will work this way on SQLServer.  DB2 should be similar.

Comment: Yes I am on DB2. DB won't allow group by in first place. So can't go till order by and top 1.

Comment: Are you saying that you can't use GROUP BY in DB2?

Comment: No, I can not group by on single column A.COLUMN_B. If I use group by  A.ID,A.COLUMN_B, result wont be same as what I want.

Answer (score -1):

Worked the oterh way around. Just used Order By on A.ID and select row with max identity column.

Comment: -1: That assumes that the order of the id is in any way relevant to the desired order of the results.  I'm going to say that , 90% of the time, in most databases, this is usually _not_ the case.  Even more problematic if attempting to order by an aggregate, which of course will not have been part of the actual row...